# Db2 sql for partition by range select

Tags: db2

I am trying to get my head around db2 partition stuff.

```
Select a.*, max(a.bloo) 
   over ( 
       partition by range (a.bloo) (starting '2014-4-20' ending '2015-1-1')
   )
   as maxmax from (
       select * from someTable
   ) a
```

I get a sql code of negative 104 for this, and I cannot decipher the docs.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish. (see [How Do I Write a Good Question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up two different things: table partitioning, which is a physical characteristic of a table, and OLAP (window) functions, which provide logical grouping of records in a query.

I guess what you wanted was something like

```
Select 
  a.*, 
  max(a.bloo) over ( partition by a.bloo ) as maxmax 
from someTable a
where
  a.bloo between '2014-4-20' and '2015-1-1'
```

However, without knowing what you wanted to achieve in the first place it's impossible to give you a definitive answer. You may want to publish some sample data and the desired output.